# How to calculate the difference in date time on Sun OS?

Tags: shell, unix, sunos

[SunOS] How to find the difference in date time?

Date 1 : 2017-01-02 17:24:33
Date 2 : 2017-01-03 22:55:02

Answer : 1770 minutes

Comment: Which version of Sun OS do you have in mind?  Solaris 11, Solaris 10, some older version of Solaris, or do you really mean Sun OS 4.x?  (The Solaris versions x are equivalent to version 5.x, IIRC.)

Comment: Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Neither Sun OS nor Solaris is Linux; the native `date` command doesn't have the facilities of GNU `date`, AFAIK. It may be obvious how you do it on Linux, but it isn't so obvious how you do it with POSIX [`date`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html) which is approximately what Sun OS or Solaris supports.

You should find [How do I get the date from two weeks ago using Solaris `date`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/232151/how-do-i-get-the-date-from-two-weeks-ago-using-solaris-date) on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com) useful.  It suggests that if you're using a recent enough version of Solaris (implying Solaris 11, I think, and excluding earlier versions), then you can use `gdate` to access the facilities of GNU `date`.  You can then convert the two given date/time values to 'seconds since the epoch', subtract them, and divide by 60 to get the number of minutes in the interval between the times.

For example:

```
date1="2017-01-02 17:24:33"
date2="2017-01-03 22:55:02"
secs1=$(gdate -d "$date1" +'%s')
secs2=$(gdate -d "$date2" +'%s')
echo $(( ($secs2 - $secs1) / 60 ))
```

The output from that is `1770`.

The `$(( … ))` is POSIX shell arithmetic, also supported by Korn shell and Bash.  I don't know whether the Solaris 11 `/bin/sh` supports it or not.  Historically, that shell was a Bourne shell without support for `$( … )` let alone `$(( … ))`.

If you don't have `gdate` already, consult the cross-referenced question for more information about optional GNU software that can be installed on Solaris from the official Solaris repositories (see [Solaris default install user tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66415/solaris-default-install-user-tools)).